# Merging Using Aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am Creating small attendance system for learning,

I've two collection :

**Employee :**

```
{
    "id": "5f474ebb12a55e2a1c4fb39f"
    "emp_status": true,
    "logAttendance": true,
    "createdAt": "2020-08-27T06:09:31.533Z",
    "empId": "10000",
    "firstName": "firstName",
    "lastName": "lastName",
    "gender": "male",
    "dob": "2020-07-11T08:53:20.691Z",
    "email": "abcd@abcd.com",
    "department": {
            "_id": "5f2f8599e5f4c015e4827c3f",
            "departmentName": "department",
            "organizationName": "department ",
        },
    "designation": {
            "_id": "5f2f85b2e5f4c015e4827c42",
            "designationName": "designation "
        },
     .
     .
     .
}
```

**Attendance :**

```
{
            "_id": "5f4a05bb09f14077c82157bb",
            "empId": "10000",
            "employee": "5f474ebb12a55e2a1c4fb39f"  
            "weekOff": false,
            "dated": "2020-08-29T07:37:31.525Z",
            "inTime": "2020-08-29T04:30:08.000Z",
            "outTime": "2020-08-30T15:30:25.000Z"
} .... x 30 days x 100 employees
```

I want it to group them by "employee" which is ObjectId from employee collection, and also populate the employee with firstName lastName.

**What I tried :**

```
const stats = await Attendance.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$employee",

        attendance: {
          $push: {
            dated: "$dated",
            weekOff: "$weekOff",
            present: "$present,
            inTime: "$inTime",
            outTime: "$outTime",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "Employee",           // " module.exports = Employee " from employee Schema;
        localField: "employee",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "employeeData",
      },
    },
  ]);
```

**Result :**

```
[{
        "_id": "5f474ebb12a55e2a1c4fb39f",  // this Id suppose to be populated with employee data 
                                            //    which is not Working.
        "attendance": [
                {
                    "dated": "2020-08-01T07:37:31.546Z",   // 01-08-2020
                    "weekOff": false,
                    "inTime": "2020-08-01T08:00:08.131Z",
                    "outTime": "2020-08-01T13:39:31.543Z",
                },
                {
                    "dated": "2020-08-02T20:44:04.245Z",   // 02-08-2020
                    "weekOff": false,
                    "inTime": "2020-08-02T04:16:16.670Z",
                    "outTime": "2020-08-02T14:27:04.529Z",
                },
               ....
},
{
        "_id": "5f474efe12a5256g1c4fb3ee",
        "attendance": [
                {
                    "dated": "2020-08-01T07:37:31.546Z",   // 01-08-2020 
                    "weekOff": false,
                    "inTime": "2020-08-01T08:00:08.131Z",
                    "outTime": "2020-08-01T13:39:31.543Z",
                },
                {
                    "dated": "2020-08-02T20:44:04.245Z" ,// 02-08-2020
                    "weekOff": false,
                    "inTime": "2020-08-02T04:16:16.670Z",
                    "outTime": "2020-08-02T14:27:04.529Z",
                },
               ....
},
......

]
```

"_id": "5f474efe12a5256g1c4fb3ee",  < ---  I Want this Id from stats to be populated with employee data which
is not Working
I tried to use lookup but not working.

Comment: Are you sure your Ateendand.employee field is an ObjectId and not a string? Otherwise you have to transform it before.

Answer (score 0):

When you use regular lookup, the `$group`  stage makes the array. So you need to unwind it to flat the array, then use the lookup. I used `$$ROOT` to get all fields, but your way is also correct if you need custom fields. If you need to re-structure fields, then you can easily use `$group`

```
db.Attendance.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$employee",
      attendance: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }          
    }        
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$attendance"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Employee",
      localField: "attendance.employee",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "employeeData",
      
    },
    
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X2x7C7KcHII)

Comment: but I'm getting employeeData  : [ ] empty array

Comment: Is working with your provided data. Please check the variable names.

Comment: That's the first thing I've checked and all correct

Comment: It should give the result. There can be two possibilities 1. There is no join 2. Variable name not correct. You can see on the demo tht is working fine, no?

Comment: But the ObjectId of Employee is exactly as in attendance.employee I did cross verified, I tried with another field "empId" but same result

Comment: Check your foreign field. It should be "id" instead of "_id" as you given in the sample data

Comment: does that help you?

Comment: No @varman I tried with other collection, checked all variables still no success

Comment: Its crazy.. the data you have provied is working here, how that working in your machine!